# GoogleAppScriptにおける定期的な承認要求が出ないようにしたい。

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

GAS(GoogleAppScript)上で、
スプレッドシート操作などのAPIを使用する際に出る**権限承認**についてです。

初回はエディター上から承認を進めて問題なく実行できていたのですが、
しばらくすると再度権限の承認が必要となって処理が実行されません。
再度表示された時はコードの変更は一切行っていません。
コンソール上での実行なら手動で承認をすればいいのですが、
トリガー起動の際に承認が要求されると処理が流れてしまっているのが現状です。

**【仕様と環境】**
主な動きはGoogleフォームの送信がトリガーとなってGASを用いてスプレッドシートに書き込みを行う仕組みです。
GASはGoogleフォームに紐づいたコンテナバインド型です。
また、doPostも利用している為、アプリケーションとしてデプロイを行なってGCPプロジェクトにも紐づけています。

**【試したこと】**
1日1回や数時間おきにGASのプロジェクトが起動されるように時間型のトリガーを用いて定期的に動かすことで、
権限を維持できないか検討しました。
ですが、数日後に権限の承認がない旨のエラー通知がメールに届きトリガー自体が実行されていなかった。